# What will i have to do after registration for domain

Tags: ftp, dns

Actually, today morning purchased my new domain in Bigrock. I dont know what to do here after. I want to upload my files to my registered domain. But how can i do this?

I'm trying to connect via filezilla to upload content of registered domain.. but getting this error

Status: Resolving address of domainname.com
Status: Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NODATA - No address associated with nodename".

also tried ftp.domainname.com

Status: Resolving address of ftp.domainame.com
Status: Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor servname provided, or not known".

What will i have to do now?

Question 1 : First step what to do?

Question 2 : what is user name and password have to give in filezilla to upload contents. Whether it is site password or acc password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you get any further, ask yourself this question. did you setup a FTP user and/or hosting? Sounds like you haven't.

If not, that is step 1. You need to get hosting setup first, during that process you should be able to use your user and pass that was setup for FTP login.

Comment: Thank you, actually hosting will take 24-48hrs to activate from registered time. This is the problem. Got it now... Thank you